# Jquery clickable table rows not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to create clickable table rows within a rails view and I am now struggling getting it working on IE.

I saw another answer to this question but I couldn't work out how it related to my situation so here goes.

Here is my jquery

```
jQuery( function($) { 
    $('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable').click( function() { 
    window.location = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
    }).find('a').hover( function() { 
        $(this).parents('tr').unbind('click'); 
    }, function() { 
        $(this).parents('tr').click( function() { 
            window.location = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

And here is some of the markup (all tags are closed) :

```
<table id="gradient-style">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last name</th>
        <th scope="col">Home phone</th>
        <th scope="col">Work phone</th>

        <th scope="col">Division</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">Give background color to the table cells to achieve seamless transition</td>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
  <tr data-href="/players/657/edit" class="odd">
    <td>joe</td>
    <td>bloggs</td>
    <td>0123456789</td>

    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>email@email.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-href="/players/676/edit" class="even">
    <td>joe</td>
    <td>bloggs2</td>
    <td>123456789</td>
    <td>123456789</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>lala@live.com</td>
  </tr>
```

The links work fine in chrome and firefox but I cannot for the life of me get them working in IE.

Any help would be massively appreciated,

Adam

**Edit: Did you mean like this **

```
jQuery( function($) { 
    $('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable').click( function() { 

         window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-href');
    }).find('a').hover( function() { 
        $(this).parents('tr').unbind('click'); 
    }, function() { 
        $(this).parents('tr').click( function() { 
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
        }); 
    });
```

**EDIT - **

It works fine if you open the developer console and then close it, unless you restart IE. 
This really has me quite confused.

Comment: Do you close `tr` tags (i.e. `</tr>`)?

Comment: Yeah they are closed, Ill update the question with the full view

Comment: try by assigning  $(this).attr('data-href') to window.location.href .
 window.location.href =  $(this).attr('data-href');

Comment: I updated with an edit showing the updated code, still working in chrome and firefox but no IE :(

Comment: It might help to show actual rendered markup without the commented markup and ruby tags in there.  For instance, there is no "a" tag in the stuff you show for the hover event.

Comment: It works if I press f12 and open the developer tools, don't have to do anything inside them it just works once you press it and then works from then on..... This is really confusing. I will switch it over to the markup now, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Switched over to the actual markup - the ruby code.

Comment: Fixed ! had a console.log still running, console.log only exists when the developer console is open in ie9. this was stopping it running.